# Working with local session and then switching to remote rdp connection

Tags: 20.04, remote-desktop

So I usually work with ubuntu on my local computer (regular ubuntu GUI, several tools open, ssh session set up and what not). From time to time I need to connect to it remotely, ideally to the same session using RDP. Ideally I would be thrown right back to session that is still active, so I can immediately resume what I was doing before I left.

I've set up xrdp and can successfully connect to my ubuntu machine, but it's a completely new session, I have to set stuff up again, before carrying on with my work. Is there any solution for my case?